# Elements conflict if I wrap class to some content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, conflict

In a WordPress website, I want to configure a set of css buttons appear in a block. So that each post have a set of buttons. I was able to set them in `inline-block`. But the issue is that when I wrap them with a new class(via jquery) in order to center using `display:block`, the buttons belonging to other posts also appear in the recent posts.

Say, the recent post named - "mypost10" has the five buttons, other post buttons appear besides the five buttons if I wrap with `main-class-wrap`.

Here is the jquery to wrap and add classes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".sub").wrapAll("<span class='main-class-wrap' />");
    jQuery(".sub-1").find('a').addClass('sub-sub-1 icon-magnifier');
    jQuery(".sub-2").find('a').addClass('sub-sub-2 icon-tools');
    jQuery(".sub-3").find('a').addClass('sub-sub-3 icon-shareable');
    jQuery(".sub-4").find('a').addClass('sub-sub-4 icon-magnifier');
    jQuery(".sub-5").find('a').addClass('sub-sub-5 icon-magnifier');
});
```

Here is the output code:

```
<span class="main-class-wrap">
        <span class="sub sub-1">
        <a href="http://link1.com" target="_blank" class="sub123 icon-one">
            Link1
        </a> 
        </span>
    <span class="sub sub-2">   
        <a href="http://link2.com" target="_blank" class="sub123 icon-two">
            Link2
        </a>
        </span>     <span class="sub sub-3">
        <a href="http://link2.com" target="_blank" class="sub123 icon-two">
            Link3
        </a>
        </span>
    <span class="sub sub-4">
        <a href="http://link2.com" target="_blank" class="sub123 icon-two">
            Link4
        </a>
        </span>
    <span class="sub sub-5">
        <a href="http://link2.com" target="_blank" class="sub123 icon-two">
            Lin5
        </a>
       </span>
    <span class="sub sub-1">
    </span>
    <span class="sub sub-2">
    </span>
    <span class="sub sub-3">
    </span>
    <span class="sub sub-4">
    </span>
    <span class="sub sub-5">
    </span>
</span>
```

I put them all in a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/4Njqn/3/)

Could any one tell me if I am doing anything wrong with the code?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you are trying to show in the fiddle.  Can you demonstrate `Say, the recent post named - "mypost10" has the five buttons, other post buttons appear besides the five buttons if I wrap with main-class-wrap.` Example in your fiddle?

Comment: @Trevor I couldn't post the entire code in fiddle, so I have posted just the sample code of the recent posts. To demonstrate, I may need to post the code atleast for three posts from the  post-list. It would be a lengthy code and will post it soon.

Comment: Meanwhile, I would like to explain more in detailed. Every posts should have a set of five buttons. I successfully able to create, wrap classes and set css for them. But the buttons of all the posts crawls to the recent(top most appeared) post. So the post at top got 15 buttons from other posts instead of it's own 5 posts. I don't know if that's because WordPress posts native behavior.